# Excel rounded number unrounds itself no matter what function is used

Tags: excel, rounding

I'm having rather strange problem. I have multiple rows and I need to get some information. I need percentage of discount that needs to be applied to D value and I get it in E column. Then I need text of that result embedded with some other data as in example. It works just fine until I hit the G column where the number magically unrounds itself to its full value. It doesn't matter what I do in E or F, G is still pulling those forgotten decimal places (up to 10). I used mod, round, fixed... I don't know anymore, it would be easier to write functions I didn't use. It's driving me crazy. Please, any idea ?
P.S. The table has more than one row, but this row is enough to show you the trouble I'm having.

```
   A  B  C   D     E            F                      G
```

1 12345   5  100 300    =1-(C1/D1)  =A1&B1&ROUND(E1*100;3)       =F1&F2&F3&F4&F5

Comment: Writing this question I thought I had figured it out and I added =TEXT(TRUNC(E2*100000);"########") in-between E and F and changed round to multiply by 1000. F (now G) is correct, however, G (now H) is still not, it has at least 10 decimal places ! GJO%#F%$%$G$%EG&W#$&F$

Comment: I dont encounter that problem. I have the correct amount of numbers after the comma. The only thing I see, is that F1 & F2 leads to the next number directly attached to the one before... Try 'F1 & " " & F2' in column G

Comment: I do need it attached directly. But, I've solved it myself. The problem occurs when using Excel 2007 and saving file as .xls rather than .xlsx - it does the difference. No idea why...

Comment: I have Excel2010 (Windows) and no problem with your code